# How many indices will be used per query in SQL/sqlite3?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, indexing

I found my query runs extremely slow, when two tables are inner joined together for a large data scale, while for a small dataset it was fine. I was told that sqlite3 can only use one index for every table in a query, but I am not sure about that, does anyone know where the information can be found? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think the correct interpretation would be one index per table *reference* in the query.  If a table is referenced multiple times, different indexes could be used.

Answer (score 0):

Much of the information about how sqlite uses indexes can be found in the following documentation urls:

- https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html
- https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html
- https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner-ng.html

Basically, each time a table is used in a query, at most one index of the table can normally be used (a notable exception is that `OR` conditions in a `WHERE` or `ON` might allow multiple indexes, one per term). The query planner tries to pick the one that will be most appropriate and fastest. Running [`ANALYZE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) on a populated database generates statistics that can be used to improve the selection when there are multiple possible indexes.

Understanding [`EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) reports is essential to figuring out how a particular query ends up being resolved and how and what indexes are involved.